# Stream Write Invalid Image Content

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I have a php script which store images from put request. The script is hosted on [Host Monster](http://www.hostmonster.com)

Here is my script

```
<?php    

$path = 'test.png';        

$put = fopen("php://input", "r");   

$fp = fopen($path, "w");    

while ($data = fread($put, 1024))
    fwrite($fp, $data);     

fclose($fp);
fclose($put);

echo 'done';        
?>
```

My script is working well. Now I have ported this script to google-appengine and now its storing invalid images. Here is app-engine script

```
<?php
$path = 'gs://my-bucket/test.png';

$options = ['gs' => ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg' , 'acl'=>'public-read']];

$ctx = stream_context_create($options); 

$put = fopen("php://input", "r");   

$fp = fopen($path, "w",false,$ctx); 

while ($data = fread($put, 1024))
    fwrite($fp, $data);     

fclose($fp);
fclose($put);

echo 'done';    
?>
```

Files are created with invalid content. Can anyone help/point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more data about what is actually being written to the bucket? Is the file length correct? What's different from what's being uploaded?

Comment: No file length is not correct. There are extra bytes in data. I have opened the stored file in notepad and compared it to other image file and data is not same. Here is source file link https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhysugy74jopklf/source.png and here is output file link https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqfi3dm4fbtxtd5/stored_file.png

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same script and it works fine for me, might be you were facing the issue because of the size of the image, as it was an issue in the PHP library, which generates the memcache key. Memcache unable to generate the key of length more than 250 bytes.Now that that bug is fixed. Find below the code snippet which i tried.It is same as yours.

```
<?php
      use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
      use google\appengine\api\log\LogService;

      $object_url = 'gs://my-bucket/test1.png';

     $options = stream_context_create( ['gs' => ['acl' => 'public-read', 
    'Content-Type' => 'image/jpg']] );

      $my_file = fopen($object_url, 'w', false, $options);
      $put = fopen("image.jpg", "r");

      while ($data = fread($put, 1024))
          fwrite($my_file, $data);
      fclose($my_file);
      fclose($put);

    echo 'done';    
?>
```